# XCUI Test - Failed to scroll to visible

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

In my UI tests, I have code that taps a button called "blah", and this is the error I am getting:

```
 Synthesize event
t =   267.72s             Scroll element to visible
t =   267.78s             Assertion Failure: UI Testing Failure - Failed to scroll to visible (by AX action) Button 0x7fc805a4f670: 
traits: 8589934601, {{264.0, 365.5}, {61.0, 60.0}}, label: 'blah', error: Error -25204 performing AXAction 2003
```

What can this be caused by?

Answer (score 1):

Button is not visible on the screen. If you watch your test run you'd see that the button is not currently available to tap. You'll need to write some code to scroll(swipe) to the correct location.